# Using timepicker on bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I try to use datepicker and timepicker on a web application with jQuery.
datepicker works well and I find the class.

Nevertheless I do not know why timepicker does not. The class does not exist and when I implement it, it does not work.

Datepicker:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control" onkeyup="datemask(this);" type="text" id="datepicker" style="width: 100px;" maxlength="10"/>
<script>
$(function () {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({nextText: "", prevText: ""});
});
</script>
```

Timepicker:

```
<input class="timepicker form-control" type="text" id="timepicker" style="width: 100px;"/>
<script>
$(function () {
      $(".timepicker").timepicker();
});
</script>
```

Suggestion or explanations about this strange problem?

Comment: Have you included the timepicker plugin on your page? Look at the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui-timepicker/info) for that tag you added to this question: That is a separate plugin from the jQuery UI set of plugins.

Comment: You are right, I had to add the JQuery plugin Thank you

Comment: No problem. Since this is a very localized problem, I'm going to suggest closing this question, as it is unlikely to help future users.